# SwiftUI: Reduce List RowSeparator size when editMode is active

Tags: swiftui

I have this code:

```
struct SomeStruct: Hashable {
    let title: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var editMode = EditMode.active
    private var items: [SomeStruct] = [
        // For code size, additionaly add items to array
        .init(title: "Title1"),
    ]
    
    @State private var items2: Set<SomeStruct> = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Press me"){
                    if items.count == items2.count {
                        items2 = []
                    } else {
                        items2 = Set(items)
                    }
                }
                
                List(items, id: \.self, selection: $items2) { item in
                    Text(item.title)
                        .listRowSeparator(.visible)
                }
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            }
            .padding()
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is, as `editMode` is always active, to have always visible separators, but to remove separator below RadioButton.

I tried to achieve this with default behaviour (to not use *.listRowSeparator(.visible)*), but when selecting all items and scrolling, separators are removed as in image below:

[imageWithRemovedSeparators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU5jD.png)

So I need to use *.listRowSeparator(.visible)*

Also tried to use:

```
.alignmentGuide(.listRowSeparatorLeading) { viewDimensions in
    return viewDimensions[.listRowSeparatorLeading]
}
```

but unsuccessfully.

It is tested on iPhone 14 Pro, iOS 16.4 with Xcode 15.2

Answer (score 0):

You maybe could try with some trick like this:

```
List(items, id: \.self, selection: $items2) { item in
                Text(item.title)
                    //.listRowSeparator(.visible)
                    .overlay(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                        Rectangle()
                            /// Adjust separator properties here
                            .fill(.quaternary.opacity(0.9))
                            .frame(height: 0.5)
                            .scaleEffect(1.2, anchor: .bottomLeading)
                            .offset(x: -50, y: 12)
                    }
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

Here's the result:

[image: Separator with overlay]

You can tune the thickness as you like using the height, or any other proprty really.
Let me know if this could be a viable solution for you!